In Livewire 3, after updating a property in the component class, the input chechbox in the Blade view does not change
I have in the order form a input text field that is binding to the accountForm property. I also have a input checkbox, bound to isChecked, if it is marked, the user account is also updated when the order is created. The checkbox is unchecked at the beginning (isChecked = false), but when the customer changes the input text, the updateAccountForm method in the class changed the property isChecked = true. This works, verified with dd, but the checkbox in the blade view remains unchecked. I am asking for your help in solving the problem. I have a feeling that it worked in Livewire 2.
I think there is a problem with re-hydration
Thanks for help.
Edit: attached video https://youtu.be/l_WR4XzacvQ
// livewire class

public $accountForm = [
        'name' => '',
        'phone' => '',
    ];

public $isChecked = false;

public function updatedAccountForm()
{
    $this->isChecked = true;
    // dd($this->isChecked); // verified if update works
}

// blade view

<input id="name" type="text" name="name" wire:model.live.debounce.500ms="accountForm.name" />
<input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" wire:model.live.debounce.500ms="accountForm.phone" />

{{-- this checkbox is not checked after a change in class, i trying wire:model or wire:model.live --}}
<label for="updateAccount">Update account</label><input id="updateAccount" wire:model.live="isChecked" type="checkbox" name="updateAccount" />

{{-- property value verification --}}
{{ $isChecked }}

I searched for a solution on stackoverflow, laracast, etc., but without success.

Now that you corrected the question it works perfectly for me. Is there any other part of the class or view that can affect the checkbox?

No, I don't think that anything else can affect the checkbox. I am attaching a video: https://youtu.be/l_WR4XzacvQ

SOLVED!
So the problem was with multiple AlpineJS instances running. In the console was Detected multiple instances of Alpine running.
This is displayed when using Laravel Breeze. The solution is to delete everything about Alpine from app.js;
Everything seems to be working properly now.
